# Analog Meter Circuit Design Help

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, circuit-design, homework

I'm not usually one to turn to these online forums, but I'm working on designing a circuit to meet the following requirements. My only problem is I'm unsure of how to begin it and have nobody to turn to for help. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

---

[image: Image of the original question text]

So far I've thought that maybe a method of using switches to separate the original voltage into lines with varying resistors might work. I also believe I'd need my meter to go at the end of whatever circuit I end up designing.

To summarize I'm thinking 1 voltage source (DC); switches to separate it to reduce the voltage and some method to get a single output to match the criteria? Is this something that's possible or should I keep brainstorming?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If the solution isn't obvious, research online, this is a start. https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-8/voltmeter-design/

Comment: this site is not a forum

Comment: your post appears to describe a school assignment ... if it is, then please use the `homework` tag

Comment: This does indeed look like homework, and we are not here to provide homework solutions. We will expect you to show significant effort yourself and ask a specific question. You do have someone to turn to...your instructor.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who contributed a helpful comment. I did a quick skim through the link about circuits and it contains useful info. Also I considered one big switch and I'll try to progress that further on that thought. I am not seeking the direct "answer" just help to point me towards the right direction on how to start this. Also not all of us the post stuff like this on this forum for the sole aim to get an easy answer, I'm asking for tips from people that understand this type of stuff and where to find the resources to get the solution. Sorry if it came off like that -JJ

Comment: Also are there any other resources you all would reccomend?

Comment: You don't need s voltage source to build an analog meter (unless it's an ohm-meter too).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is homework without an attempt at a solution and because there are too many problems in one question

Comment: I've received enough information, the question can be closed. Thank you all for the help!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Impressive assignment.  This is old-school.

You will need one big switch with 10 positions.  Common (negative) on common leg.  Positive feeds into switch via different circuits as required.

You have characteristics of meter movement (MM).  Work out voltage drop across MM.  That is 130mV.  Maximum current MM can experience is 1mA.  Maximum voltage: 130mV.  Use that information to design each meter separately.  10 different circuits.  Start at ammeter.

Ammeter: shunts go in parallel with MM.  1mA does not need a shunt.

DC Voltmeter: series droping resistors go in series with MM.

AC Voltmeter: same as DC Voltmeter plus a diode.